# How to do Page Flip Effect in Sencha Touch?

Tags: sencha-touch-2, page-flipping

I want to do page flip effect in sencha touch. There are no.of jquery plugins are available in web and these plugins having so much lines of code.it is bit hard to understand.

There is another issue i read from sencha forum ( http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthre...l=1#post723554 ). some of flip like transitions are not working in mobiles except ios devices.

I have also tested in android and htc. those are not working.

so can you give any idea how to do page flip effect in sencha touch which works on all mobiles and ipad devices ??

Please see the below link. i want this type of effect.

http://www.turnjs.com/#samples/magazine3/4

Answer (score 0):

Sencha does not a mechanism to do what you are asking but you can include the page.js files in your project and use it within a sencha container as you require...